# How to display different text in a textview according to date in android app?

Tags: android

I am very new at coding and want to develop an android app that display new content according the day you are opening the app.

For example : 20 days to eat better
Day 1 (user open the app), then the message is "XXXXXX"
Day 2 (user open the app), the the message is "YYYYY"

Day 1 is a the day the user download the app.

I understood that I need to use "timestamp" as a  string, but how can I do it ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about what you are trying to achieve. But based on what I understood. You just want to get the current day

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();// sets the current date
calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);// gets the current day returns an integer value
calendar.getTime();// gets the current date and returns a Date Object
```

You can start from here. The calendar class offers you different values for the current calendar date. I'm pretty sure all you need to know is available if you just tried to search the web. But to give you something to work on, experiment with the Calendar class for date manipulations.

EDIT:

If you want to display a certain string based on the date/day. What you can do is to create an array and user the date/day value to get the string.

```
String[] stringArray = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5", "Text6", "Text7"};
String theStringYouWant = stringArray[calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)];
```

You can use this approach if you have short strings and limited record. But if you have tons of data, you might want to utilize a database to store your data, and use this approach.

Comment: Hi ! Thank for answering and sorry for not being clear. I don't want to display the date , but a different text depending on the Day the app have been download. Like a new quote everyday. Dors that make sens for you ?